# VBS Computer Info Script

Tags: vbscript, wmi

Can someone help me modify this please?

Instead of the dialog box appearing at the start to ask for computer ID/Name, is there anyway for this to be automatically put in, so its all automatic? And at the end, not to open the file, just to have it stored on the hdd (same dir as script)

```
On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Dim strComputer, objWMIService, propValue, objItem
Dim strUserName, strPassword, colItems, SWBemlocator

' This section queries for the workstation to be scanned.
strComputer = inputbox ("Workstation", "Enter the workstation ID to scan.",".")
UserName = ""
Password = ""
ImgDir = "C:\Scripts\images\"

'Sets up the connections and objects to be used throughout the script.
Set SWBemlocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\CIMV2",strUserName,strPassword)

'This determines the current date and time of the PC being scanned.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    If objItem.Minute < 10 Then
        theMinutes = "0" & objItem.Minute
    Else
        theMinutes = objItem.Minute
    End If
    If objItem.Second < 10 Then
        theSeconds = "0" & objItem.Second
    Else
        theSeconds = objItem.Second
    End If
    DateTime = objItem.Month & "/" & objItem.Day & "/" & objItem.Year & " - " & objItem.Hour & ":" & theMinutes & ":" & theSeconds
Next

'Gets some information about the operating system including service pack level.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    WKID = objItem.CSName
    WKOS = objItem.Caption
    ServicePack = objItem.ServicePackMajorVersion & "." & objItem.ServicePackMinorVersion
Next

'This section returns the Video card and current resolution.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DisplayConfiguration",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    VideoCard = objItem.DeviceName
    Resolution = objItem.PelsWidth & " x " & objItem.PelsHeight & " x " & objItem.BitsPerPel & " bits"
Next

'This section returns the Video card memory.
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_VideoController")
For Each objItem in colItems
    VideoMemory = objItem.AdapterRAM/1024/1024
Next

'This returns various system information including current logged on user, domain, memory, manufacture and model.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    UserName = objItem.UserName
    Domain = objItem.Domain
    TotalMemory = int((objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1024)/1024+1)
    Manufacturer = objItem.Manufacturer
    Model = objItem.Model
Next

'This determines the total hard drive space and free hard drive space.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where Name='C:'",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    FreeHDSpace = Fix(((objItem.FreeSpace/1024)/1024)/1024)
    TotalHDSpace = Fix(((objItem.Size/1024)/1024)/1024)
Next

'This section returns the default printer and printer port.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer where Default=True", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    Printer = objItem.Name
    PortName = objItem.PortName
Next

'This returns the CPU information.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    CPUDesc = LTrim(objItem.Name)
Next

'This returns the current uptime (time since last reboot) of the system.
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems
    dtmBootup = objOS.LastBootUpTime
    dtmLastBootupTime = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    dtmSystemUptime = DateDiff("h", dtmLastBootUpTime, Now)
    Uptime = dtmSystemUptime
Next
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmBootup, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(dtmBootup, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmBootup, 4) & " " & Mid (dtmBootup, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup,13, 2))
End Function

'This sets up the Internet Explorer window in order to show the results.
Set objExplorer = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
With objExplorer
    .Navigate "about:Blank"
    .Toolbar = 0
    .StatusBar = 0
    .Width = 800
    .Height = 600
    .Left = 75
    .Top = 0
    .Visible = 1
End With
Set fileOutput = objExplorer.Document

'This is the code for the web page to be displayed.
fileOutput.Open
fileOutput.WriteLn "<html>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "    <head>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "        <title>System Information for '" & WKID & "' </title>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "    </head>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "    <body bgcolor='#FFFFFF' text='#000000' link='#0000FF' vlink='000099' alink='#00FF00'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "        <center>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "            <h3>Workstaion/Server Information for " & WKID & "</h3>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "            <table border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' width='95%'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                <tr><td background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                    <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                        <tr><td>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                            <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                <tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                    <td width='5%' align='left' valign='middle' background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'><img src='" & ImgDir & "write.gif'></td>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                    <td width='95%' align='left' valign='middle' background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'> <font color='#FFFFFF' size='5'>WKInfo - </font><font color='#FFFFFF' size='3'>General information on the Workstation.</font></td>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                </tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                    <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Last Scanned</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Date/Time</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & DateTime & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>System Uptime</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Uptime & " hours</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Workstation ID</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & WKID & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Domain</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Domain & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>UserName</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & UserName & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General OS Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Operating System</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & WKOS & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Service Pack</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & ServicePack & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Computer Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Manufacturer</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Manufacturer & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Model</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Model & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Hardware Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>CPU</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & CPUDesc & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Memory</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & TotalMemory & " MB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Total HD Space</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & TotalHDSpace & " GB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Free HD Space</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & FreeHDSpace & " GB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Video Card Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Video Card</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & VideoCard & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Resolution</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Resolution & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Memory</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & VideoMemory & " MB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Default Printer Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Printer</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Printer & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Port Name</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & PortName & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Shared Directories</i></b></TD></TR>"
'This sextion lists all the current shares enabled on the PC.
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                                <TR><TD width='30%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Name</b></td><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Path</b><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Description</b></td><tr>"
Set colShares = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Share")
For each objShare in colShares
    fileOutput.WriteLn "                                                <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><i>" & objShare.Name & "</i></TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & objShare.Path & "</i></TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & objShare.Caption & "</i></td></tr>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the current services and their status.
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Current Service Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                                <TR><TD width='70%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Service Name</b></td><TD width='30%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Service State</b></td><tr>"
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service")
For Each objService in colRunningServices
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                            <TR><TD align='left' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objService.DisplayName & "</TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=center><i>" & objService.State & "</i></td></tr>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the current running processes and some information.
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Current Process Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                                <TR><TD width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>PID</b></td><TD width='35%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Process Name</b></td><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Owner</b></td><TD width='15%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Memory</b></td></tr>"
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
colProperties = objProcess.GetOwner(strNameOfUser,strUserDomain)
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                                <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.Handle & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.Name & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & strUserDomain & "\" & strNameOfUser & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.WorkingSetSize/1024 & " kb</td><tr>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the currently installed software on the machine.
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Installed Software</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Product")
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
    fileOutput.WriteLn"                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
    fileOutput.WriteLn"                                                <tr><td align=left bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Caption:</b></td><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Caption & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLn"                                                <tr><td align=left bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Install Location:</b></td><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.InstallLocation & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLn"                                                <tr><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Name</b></td><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Vendor</b></td><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Version</b></td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLn"                                                <tr><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Name & "</td><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Vendor & "</td><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Version & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLn"                                                <tr height=2><td height=10 align=center bgcolor=midnightblue colspan=3></td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLn"                                            </table>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                        </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                    </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                                </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                        </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                    </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "                </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "            <p><small></small></p>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "        </center>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "    </body>"
fileOutput.WriteLn "<html>"
fileOutput.close
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code.  It takes as command line arguments the workstation name to query, as well as two optional parameters, username and password.  Instead of outputting the results to an IE window, I made a slight change to use the File System object to output your html code to a file called: workstation.html, where workstation is the actual workstation name that was scanned as passed to the script.

The sections of code I added are in two locations, at the top and right before the IE window portion, I have put ' ************* comments around both so you can spot them quickly.  I left your fileoutput var but modified it from fileOutput.writeln to fileOutput.writeline.

For more detail on the [**FileSystemObject check out the MSDN article here.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(VS.85).aspx)

For detail on [**command line options with cscript.exe check out this MSDN article.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fs17b0s(VS.85).aspx)

Here is a MS TechNet page with good information on [**using command line arguments in VBS.**](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/guide/sas_wsh_ywsa.mspx?mfr=true)

```
On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Dim strComputer, objWMIService, propValue, objItem
Dim strUserName, strPassword, colItems, SWBemlocator

ImgDir = "C:\Scripts\images\"

' *******************************************************************
' This section gets workstation name, username and password from the command prompt.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

If objArgs.Count = 1 then
    strComputer = objArgs(0)
    UserName = ""
    Password = ""
ElseIf objArgs.Count = 3 then
    strComputer = objArgs(0)
    UserName = objArgs(1)
    Password = objArgs(2)
Else
    wscript.echo "SYNTAX:  cscript scan.vbs [machinename] [username] [password]"
    wscript.echo "Parameter: Machinename - required"
    wscript.echo "Parameter: username - optional"
    wscript.echo "Parameter: password- required if username provided."
    wscript.quit
End If
' *******************************************************************

'Sets up the connections and opjects to be used throughout the script.
Set SWBemlocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\CIMV2",strUserName,strPassword)

'This determines the current date and time of the PC being scanned.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    If objItem.Minute < 10 Then
        theMinutes = "0" & objItem.Minute
    Else
        theMinutes = objItem.Minute
    End If
    If objItem.Second < 10 Then
        theSeconds = "0" & objItem.Second
    Else
        theSeconds = objItem.Second
    End If
    DateTime = objItem.Month & "/" & objItem.Day & "/" & objItem.Year & " - " & objItem.Hour & ":" & theMinutes & ":" & theSeconds
Next

'Gets some ingomation about the Operating System including Service Pack level.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    WKID = objItem.CSName
    WKOS = objItem.Caption
    ServicePack = objItem.ServicePackMajorVersion & "." & objItem.ServicePackMinorVersion
Next

'This section returns the Video card and current resolution.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DisplayConfiguration",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    VideoCard = objItem.DeviceName
    Resolution = objItem.PelsWidth & " x " & objItem.PelsHeight & " x " & objItem.BitsPerPel & " bits"
Next

'This section returns the Video card memory.
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_VideoController")
For Each objItem in colItems
    VideoMemory = objItem.AdapterRAM/1024/1024
Next

'This returns various system information including current logged on user, domain, memory, manufacture and model.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    UserName = objItem.UserName
    Domain = objItem.Domain
    TotalMemory = int((objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1024)/1024+1)
    Manufacturer = objItem.Manufacturer
    Model = objItem.Model
Next

'This determines the total hard drive space and free hard drive space.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where Name='C:'",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    FreeHDSpace = Fix(((objItem.FreeSpace/1024)/1024)/1024)
    TotalHDSpace = Fix(((objItem.Size/1024)/1024)/1024)
Next

'This section returns the default printer and printer port.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer where Default=True", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    Printer = objItem.Name
    PortName = objItem.PortName
Next

'This returns the CPU information.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    CPUDesc = LTrim(objItem.Name)
Next

'This returns the current uptime (time since last reboot) of the system.
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems
    dtmBootup = objOS.LastBootUpTime
    dtmLastBootupTime = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    dtmSystemUptime = DateDiff("h", dtmLastBootUpTime, Now)
    Uptime = dtmSystemUptime
Next
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmBootup, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(dtmBootup, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmBootup, 4) & " " & Mid (dtmBootup, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup,13, 2))
End Function

' *******************************************************************
Const TristateFalse = 0
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fileOutput = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\scan_results\" & strComputer & ".html", ForWriting, True, TristateFalse)
' *******************************************************************

'This is the code for the web page to be displayed.
fileOutput.writeline "<html>"
fileOutput.writeline "    <head>"
fileOutput.writeline "        <title>System Information for '" & WKID & "' </title>"
fileOutput.writeline "    </head>"
fileOutput.writeline "    <body bgcolor='#FFFFFF' text='#000000' link='#0000FF' vlink='000099' alink='#00FF00'>"
fileOutput.writeline "        <center>"
fileOutput.writeline "            <h3>Workstaion/Server Information for " & WKID & "</h3>"
fileOutput.writeline "            <table border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' width='95%'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                <tr><td background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                    <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                        <tr><td>"
fileOutput.writeline "                            <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                <tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                    <td width='5%' align='left' valign='middle' background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'><img src='" & ImgDir & "write.gif'></td>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                    <td width='95%' align='left' valign='middle' background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'> <font color='#FFFFFF' size='5'>WKInfo - </font><font color='#FFFFFF' size='3'>General information on the Workstation.</font></td>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                </tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                    <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Last Scanned</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Date/Time</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & DateTime & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>System Uptime</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Uptime & " hours</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Workstation ID</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & WKID & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Domain</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Domain & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>UserName</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & UserName & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General OS Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Operating System</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & WKOS & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Service Pack</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & ServicePack & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Computer Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Manufacturer</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Manufacturer & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Model</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Model & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Hardware Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>CPU</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & CPUDesc & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Memory</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & TotalMemory & " MB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Total HD Space</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & TotalHDSpace & " GB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Free HD Space</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & FreeHDSpace & " GB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Video Card Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Video Card</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & VideoCard & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Resolution</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Resolution & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Memory</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & VideoMemory & " MB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Default Printer Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Printer</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Printer & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Port Name</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & PortName & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Shared Directories</i></b></TD></TR>"
'This sextion lists all the current shares enabled on the PC.
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                                <TR><TD width='30%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Name</b></td><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Path</b><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Description</b></td><tr>"
Set colShares = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Share")
For each objShare in colShares
    fileOutput.writeline "                                                <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><i>" & objShare.Name & "</i></TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & objShare.Path & "</i></TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & objShare.Caption & "</i></td></tr>"
Next
fileOutput.writeline "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the current services and their status.
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Current Service Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                                <TR><TD width='70%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Service Name</b></td><TD width='30%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Service State</b></td><tr>"
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service")
For Each objService in colRunningServices
fileOutput.writeline "                                            <TR><TD align='left' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objService.DisplayName & "</TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=center><i>" & objService.State & "</i></td></tr>"
Next
fileOutput.writeline "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the current running processes and some information.
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Current Process Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                                <TR><TD width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>PID</b></td><TD width='35%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Process Name</b></td><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Owner</b></td><TD width='15%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Memory</b></td></tr>"
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
colProperties = objProcess.GetOwner(strNameOfUser,strUserDomain)
fileOutput.writeline "                                                <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.Handle & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.Name & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & strUserDomain & "\" & strNameOfUser & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.WorkingSetSize/1024 & " kb</td><tr>"
Next
fileOutput.writeline "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        </td></tr>"

'This section lists all the currently installed software on the machine.
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Installed Software</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Product")
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
    fileOutput.writeline"                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
    fileOutput.writeline"                                                <tr><td align=left bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Caption:</b></td><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Caption & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.writeline"                                                <tr><td align=left bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Install Location:</b></td><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.InstallLocation & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.writeline"                                                <tr><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Name</b></td><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Vendor</b></td><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Version</b></td></tr>"
    fileOutput.writeline"                                                <tr><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Name & "</td><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Vendor & "</td><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Version & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.writeline"                                                <tr height=2><td height=10 align=center bgcolor=midnightblue colspan=3></td></tr>"
    fileOutput.writeline"                                            </table>"
Next

fileOutput.writeline "                                        </td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                    </table>"
fileOutput.writeline "                                </td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                            </table>"
fileOutput.writeline "                        </td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "                    </table>"
fileOutput.writeline "                </td></tr>"
fileOutput.writeline "            </table>"
fileOutput.writeline "            <p><small></small></p>"
fileOutput.writeline "        </center>"
fileOutput.writeline "    </body>"
fileOutput.writeline "<html>"
fileOutput.close
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at

[SWbemLocator.ConnectServer Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393720.aspx)

you will see that the computer name is optional so just use , to get the details from the computer running the script.

ie:

```
Set objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer( ,"root\CIMV2",strUserName,strPassword)
```

Then don't open an ie document, just open and write to a file, using writeLine instead of writeLn.

Also change this line:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

to

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified copy that shows three different ways to "hard-code" in the computername, or just use the local computer (by ".", "127.0.0.1", or "PCNAME").
It will also save out a "MyFile.log" with the results.

```
On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Dim strComputer, objWMIService, propValue, objItem
Dim strUserName, strPassword, colItems, SWBemlocator

' This section queries for the workstation to be scanned.
strComputer = "." ' . = local computer, you can substitute it by name, or ip
strComputer = "REMOTEPC" ' example of a remote pc by computername
strComputer = "127.0.0.1" ' local computer pulled up via ip
UserName = ""
Password = ""
ImgDir = "C:\Scripts\images\"

'Sets up the connections and objects to be used throughout the script.
Set SWBemlocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\CIMV2",strUserName,strPassword)

'This determines the current date and time of the PC being scanned.
Dim DateTime
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    If objItem.Minute < 10 Then
        theMinutes = "0" & objItem.Minute
    Else
        theMinutes = objItem.Minute
    End If
    If objItem.Second < 10 Then
        theSeconds = "0" & objItem.Second
    Else
        theSeconds = objItem.Second
    End If
    DateTime = objItem.Month & "/" & objItem.Day & "/" & objItem.Year & " - " & objItem.Hour & ":" & theMinutes & ":" & theSeconds
Next

Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("MyFile.log", True)
MyFile.WriteLine(strComputer & " -> " & DateTime)
MyFile.Close

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I actually got rid of the login box at the start just be removing these lines here..

```
' This section queries for the workstation to be scanned.
strComputer = inputbox ("Workstation", "Enter the workstation ID to scan.",".")
UserName = ""
Password = ""
ImgDir = "C:\Scripts\images\"
```

Now if only i knew how to modify it so it saves the html to the hard drive instead of just opening it. I'm not a VB scripter, I do HTML only lol

Comment: The code I added has a small example of how to use the FileSystemObject to write the files you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completed file, it writes to x.html in the current folder:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Dim strComputer, objWMIService, propValue, objItem
Dim strUserName, strPassword, colItems, SWBemlocator

' This section queries for the workstation to be scanned.
UserName = ""
Password = ""
strComputer = "127.1.1.1"
ImgDir = "C:\Scripts\images\"

'Sets up the connections and opjects to be used throughout the script.
Set SWBemlocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(,"root\CIMV2",strUserName,strPassword)

'This determines the current date and time of the PC being scanned.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    If objItem.Minute < 10 Then
        theMinutes = "0" & objItem.Minute
    Else
        theMinutes = objItem.Minute
    End If
    If objItem.Second < 10 Then
        theSeconds = "0" & objItem.Second
    Else
        theSeconds = objItem.Second
    End If
    DateTime = objItem.Month & "/" & objItem.Day & "/" & objItem.Year & " - " & objItem.Hour & ":" & theMinutes & ":" & theSeconds
Next

'Gets some ingomation about the Operating System including Service Pack level.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    WKID = objItem.CSName
    WKOS = objItem.Caption
    ServicePack = objItem.ServicePackMajorVersion & "." & objItem.ServicePackMinorVersion
Next

'This section returns the Video card and current resolution.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DisplayConfiguration",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    VideoCard = objItem.DeviceName
    Resolution = objItem.PelsWidth & " x " & objItem.PelsHeight & " x " & objItem.BitsPerPel & " bits"
Next

'This section returns the Video card memory.
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_VideoController")
For Each objItem in colItems
    VideoMemory = objItem.AdapterRAM/1024/1024
Next

'This returns various system information including current logged on user, domain, memory, manufacture and model.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    UserName = objItem.UserName
    Domain = objItem.Domain
    TotalMemory = int((objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory/1024)/1024+1)
    Manufacturer = objItem.Manufacturer
    Model = objItem.Model
Next

'This determines the total hard drive space and free hard drive space.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk Where Name='C:'",,48)
For Each objItem in colItems
    FreeHDSpace = Fix(((objItem.FreeSpace/1024)/1024)/1024)
    TotalHDSpace = Fix(((objItem.Size/1024)/1024)/1024)
Next

'This section returns the default printer and printer port.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer where Default=True", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    Printer = objItem.Name
    PortName = objItem.PortName
Next

'This returns the CPU information.
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
For Each objItem in colItems
    CPUDesc = LTrim(objItem.Name)
Next

'This returns the current uptime (time since last reboot) of the system.
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems
    dtmBootup = objOS.LastBootUpTime
    dtmLastBootupTime = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    dtmSystemUptime = DateDiff("h", dtmLastBootUpTime, Now)
    Uptime = dtmSystemUptime
Next
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup)
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmBootup, 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(dtmBootup, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmBootup, 4) & " " & Mid (dtmBootup, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup,13, 2))
End Function

dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' -- The heart of the create file script -----------------------
' -- Creates the file using the value of strFile on Line 11
' --------------------------------------------------------------
Set fileOutput = objFSO.CreateTextFile( "x.html", true )

'Set fileOutput = objExplorer.Document

'This is the code for the web page to be displayed.

fileOutput.WriteLine "<html>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "    <head>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "        <title>System Information for '" & WKID & "' </title>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "    </head>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "    <body bgcolor='#FFFFFF' text='#000000' link='#0000FF' vlink='000099' alink='#00FF00'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "        <center>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "            <h3>Workstaion/Server Information for " & WKID & "</h3>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "            <table border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' width='95%'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                <tr><td background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                    <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                        <tr><td>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                            <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                <tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                    <td width='5%' align='left' valign='middle' background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'><img src='" & ImgDir & "write.gif'></td>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                    <td width='95%' align='left' valign='middle' background='" & ImgDir & "blue_spacer.gif'> <font color='#FFFFFF' size='5'>WKInfo - </font><font color='#FFFFFF' size='3'>General information on the Workstation.</font></td>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                </tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                    <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Last Scanned</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Date/Time</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & DateTime & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>System Uptime</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Uptime & " hours</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Workstation ID</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & WKID & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Domain</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Domain & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>UserName</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & UserName & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General OS Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Operating System</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & WKOS & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Service Pack</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & ServicePack & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Computer Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Manufacturer</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Manufacturer & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Model</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Model & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Hardware Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>CPU</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & CPUDesc & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Memory</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & TotalMemory & " MB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Total HD Space</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & TotalHDSpace & " GB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Free HD Space</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & FreeHDSpace & " GB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>General Video Card Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Video Card</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & VideoCard & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Resolution</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Resolution & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Memory</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & VideoMemory & " MB</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Default Printer Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Printer</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & Printer & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'>Port Name</TD><td width='70%' bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & PortName & "</i></td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Shared Directories</i></b></TD></TR>"
'This sextion lists all the current shares enabled on the PC.
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                                <TR><TD width='30%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Name</b></td><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Path</b><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Description</b></td><tr>"
Set colShares = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Share")
For each objShare in colShares
    fileOutput.WriteLine "                                                <TR><TD width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'><i>" & objShare.Name & "</i></TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & objShare.Path & "</i></TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=left><i>" & objShare.Caption & "</i></td></tr>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the current services and their status.
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Current Service Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                                <TR><TD width='70%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Service Name</b></td><TD width='30%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Service State</b></td><tr>"
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service")
For Each objService in colRunningServices
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                            <TR><TD align='left' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objService.DisplayName & "</TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=center><i>" & objService.State & "</i></td></tr>"
    wscript.echo  "                                            <TR><TD align='left' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objService.DisplayName & "</TD><td bgcolor=#f0f0f0 align=center><i>" & objService.State & "</i></td></tr>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the current running processes and some information.
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Current Process Information</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                                <TR><TD width='10%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>PID</b></td><TD width='35%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Process Name</b></td><TD width='40%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Owner</b></td><TD width='15%' align='center' bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Memory</b></td></tr>"
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
colProperties = objProcess.GetOwner(strNameOfUser,strUserDomain)
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                                <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.Handle & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.Name & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & strUserDomain & "\" & strNameOfUser & "</td><TD align='center' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>" & objProcess.WorkingSetSize/1024 & " kb</td><tr>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        </td></tr>"
'This section lists all the currently installed software on the machine.
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <TR><TD align='center' bgcolor='#d0d0d0' colspan='2'><b><i>Installed Software</i></b></TD></TR>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        <tr><td colspan='2' bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>"
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Product")
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
    fileOutput.WriteLine"                                            <TABLE width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' border='1' bordercolor='#c0c0c0' bordercolordark='#ffffff' bordercolorlight='#c0c0c0'>"
    fileOutput.WriteLine"                                                <tr><td align=left bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Caption:</b></td><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Caption & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLine"                                                <tr><td align=left bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Install Location:</b></td><td colspan=2 bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.InstallLocation & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLine"                                                <tr><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Name</b></td><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Vendor</b></td><td width=30% align=center bgcolor='#e0e0e0'><b>Version</b></td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLine"                                                <tr><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Name & "</td><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Vendor & "</td><td align=center bgcolor=#f0f0f0>" & objSoftware.Version & "</td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLine"                                                <tr height=2><td height=10 align=center bgcolor=midnightblue colspan=3></td></tr>"
    fileOutput.WriteLine"                                            </table>"
Next
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                        </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                    </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                                </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                        </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                    </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "                </td></tr>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "            </table>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "            <p><small></small></p>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "        </center>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "    </body>"
fileOutput.WriteLine "<html>"
fileOutput.close
WScript.Quit
```