# Executing VBS Code in VBA with admin rights

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

how are you doing?

I want to execute VBS code in a VBA environment, in this case I am working in the VB editor in MS Excel 2010. Sadly I have no idea how to convert the VBS code so VBA is able to execute it.

To give an idea about what I am working on: I want to execute a VBS command prompt that needs Admin rights. This prompt will restart a process on a different PC in the network. The VBS code works perfectly fine, when executed via cmd. The reason I want to use VBA is that there are a lot PC's in the network and I want to use a loop to execute the VBS code for every PC.

OK, here is the VBS code:

```
strComputer = "Computername"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
intReturn = objWMIService.Create("c:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint  Protection\12.1.1000.157.105\Bin64\smc.exe -stop", Null, Null, intProcessID)
Wscript.Sleep 10000
intReturn2 = objWMIService.Create("c:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.1000.157.105\Bin64\smc.exe -start", Null, Null, intProcessID)
```

The question is now, how do I get this code sample in to my VBA environment? I know how to execute the VBS file itself through VBA, but that is not enough, because I need a variable. Also the admin rights are up to the question.

OK, here is an update, I have now this code in my VBA, but I am not able to get things started, I also tried to implement the runas admin:

```
Sub run_vbs_script()
Dim strComputer As String
'Dim WshShell
Dim objShell
Dim objWMIService
Dim dDate As Date

strComputer = "IEDBR8D60CR"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

RunasStruser = "runas /user:Username Domain\domain name"

objShell.Run RunasStruser, 0

objShell.SendKeys "password"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")

intReturn = objWMIService.Create("c:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint  Protection\12.1.1000.157.105\Bin64\smc.exe -stop", Null, Null, intProcessID)

dDate = DateAdd("s", 10, DateTime.Now)
Do While dDate > DateTime.Now
    DoEvents
Loop

intReturn2 = objWMIService.Create("c:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.1000.157.105\Bin64\smc.exe -start", Null, Null, intProcessID)

Set objShell = Nothing
Set objWMIService = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you the administrator or do you have admin Rights?

Comment: `I want to execute VBS code in a VBA environment`, so why the vb.net tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a .vbs scipt from Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133126/calling-a-vbs-scipt-from-excel-vba)

Comment: If you need to connect to a remote PC using specific credentials then it might be simpler to use `SWBemlocator.ConnectServer` Eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716571/vbs-computer-info-script   Your VBscript should translate fairly easily to VBA.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input, I will have a look, and yes I have admin rights in the network at question

Comment: ok, I updated my code, would need some feedback on that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA Editor in excel you need to add a reference to WMI Scripting

```
    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim objShell
    Dim objWMIService
    Dim dDate As Date
    strComputer = "Computer"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
    intReturn = objWMIService.Create("c:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint  Protection\12.1.1000.157.105\Bin64\smc.exe -stop", Null, Null, intProcessID)

    dDate = DateAdd("s", 10, DateTime.Now)
    Do While dDate > DateTime.Now
        DoEvents
    Loop
    intReturn2 = objWMIService.Create("c:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.1000.157.105\Bin64\smc.exe -start", Null, Null, intProcessID)

    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
```

Comment: OK, this seems to be the right way. Now I only need to run this code with admin rights. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[This site has example code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=811) for ending a process via WMI using vba. Take a look. The example closes notepad.exe, but I'm sure you could have it do the same for symantec

Comment: Thank you, will take a look and come back with results.